# How to execute cd commands using java Runtime in a single cmd window

Tags: java, cmd

I need to execute the following Change directories commands into the cmd prompt, but using java to execute them. the dir command works fine , but not the cd ones. I have to execute them in a single cmd windows

```
cd inputDir
dir
cd outputDir
```

inputDir and outputDir are directories from the windows.

Java Snippet:

```
ArrayList<String> dosCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
Process p;
for (int i=0;i< dosCommands.size();i++){
    p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+dosCommands.get(i)); 
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line=reader.readLine();
    while(line!=null) 
    { 
        System.out.println(line); 
        line=reader.readLine(); 
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the argument to cmd.exe /k instead of /c

```
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /k "+dosCommands.get(i));
```

I had to remove the

```
p.waitFor();
```

method, because I was getting stucked in it.
Doing so, know I do get stucked in the

```
line.reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Could you describe in more details what "does not work" mean? Could you provide some output of your code and what you expect to happen?

Comment: The command works but you dont get any answer. After the command is executed the cmd.exe is closed.

Comment: @IvanMushketyk Yes, When I execute the cd inputDir, it shold change directory to the input dir directory. I check that by executing a dir command after the cd inputDir. The dir command print another directory unfortunately.

Comment: Do by any chance you change directory from one partition to another one? If so you need to use "cd <partition-letter>" first and then cd <target-path>

Comment: Here are some of the cd commands I tried to execute:
cd C:\Users\eleite\Workspace\RunCmd\Petrel_Logs
cd C:\Users\eleite\Workspace\RunCmd\Petrel2014LicenseModuleLogging

Answer (score 2):

use

```
cmd.exe /K
```

Not

```
cmd.exe /c
```

You can find more about [cmd params here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

With /c, cmd finishes and exit. With /k, it does not exit.

**__UPDATE__**

What I mean is as follows:

```
cd inputDir
dir
cd outputDir
exit
```

Pay attention to the last line please.

**__UPDATE 2__**

Please use something similar in your code to find out what is the current working directory, according to running process:

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  }
}
```

After that, let's make sure that the folders you are trying to cd to exists in that folder.

Comment: That seems to be a path to the solution, but now I cant read the output of a line and get stucked at the p.waitFor();

Comment: Did you try adding an exit statement at the end of your batch file ?

Comment: I need to execute all the commands in a single cmd window, not one by one.

Comment: @Eduardox23 Here is code example: http://ideone.com/KjVOjc (not working on ideone but should work on your Windows).

Comment: @Eduardox23 Did you at least make any progress ? If so, please update your question so we know where you are at. If not, would you post what do you after you run the script ? (Like a screen shot, error etc).

Comment: @alp I did updated the question, but unfortunately I did not made any progress. I Already tested the commands in the cmd window and they work, but not when passed as parameters in the java.

Answer (score 1):

Try this experiment:  Open a command window (using your mouse and/or keyboard, not with code).  Now change to a different directory, with a command like `cd \` or `cd C:\Windows`.

Then open a second command window.  What is its current directory?  Did it remember what you did in the first command window?

It didn't, because each time you run `cmd.exe` you are starting a new process, with its own current directory state.

In your code, you are executing a new cmd.exe process in each iteration of your for-loop.  Each time you start a new cmd.exe, it has no awareness of what the current directory may be in other cmd.exe instances.

You can set the current directory in which a process executes:

```
String inputDir = "C:\\Users\\eleite\\Workspace\\RunCmd\\Petrel_Logs";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " + dosCommands.get(i),
    null, inputDir);
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Is there a way to execute all the commands in a single cmd window ? so I do not have to pass the dir with the command ?

Comment: Write the commands to a .bat file, and pass it to cmd.exe /c.

Comment: @Eduardox23 You can pass each command to Process handling console via its input stream. If you don't want to do this in main thread create separate one.

Comment: @vgr I don't want o use a .bat file, I want all the commands to be inside the java code.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm sory i did not get it, can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

- create process simulating console
- and make this console execute few commands
- and after these commands are executed continue code from main thread

then try this code

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/k");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);//redirect process output to System.out
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);//redirect process output to System.err
Process p = pb.start();

try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()), true)){
    pw.println("dir");//execute command 1, for instance "dir"
    pw.println("ver");//execute command 2, for instance "ver"
    //... rest of commands
    pw.println("exit");//when last command finished, exit console
}
p.waitFor();//this will make main thread wait till process (console) will finish (will be closed)
//here we place rest of code which should be executed after console after console process will finish
System.out.println("---------------- after process ended ----------------");
```

So if you want list of commands you want to execute simply place them here:

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()), true)){

    //here and execute them like 
    for (String command : dosCommands){
        pw.println(command);
    }        

    pw.println("exit");//when last command finished, exit console
}
```